# Reference request - Linear Programming for Cost Curve Analysis

Tags: reference-request, optimization, linear-programming

I was hoping that someone could offer what may be a niche area of optimization, namely the applications of linear programming or optimization to engineering, specifically cost curve analysis of power generators.

i ask in Math.Stack as I see I am more interested in the mathematics of optimization here rather than the power systems engineering point of view.

Warm Regards,
Bacon.

Comment: Any luck on [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.nl/scholar?q="cost+curve+analysis"+"optimization"+"power")?

Comment: @LinAlg had a quick look nothing jumping out, thanks for the tip though.

Comment: There is a ton of literature about investment planning in energy markets. Typically these models are nonlinear. See e.g. Gabriel e.a. Complementarity Modeling in Energy Markets.This is a very nice intro into the mathematical models used in this area. This is on the intersection between engineering and economics.